# GAE webapp2 unicode flag in URL pattern

Tags: google-app-engine, url, unicode, python-2.7

I want to be able to accept URLs with a unicode alphanumeric string:

```
/Search/hello
/Search/hablé
/Search/我会明白
```

[Edit]*I realize the URLs will be URI percent encoded, but based on what I've tried out, it seems like the webapp2 module decodes the percent encoding, so my question still stands.*

As a heads-up, I'm using GAE 1.6.5, webapp2 and python 2.7.

In python, I would use the following regex with the re.UNICODE flag set to match the above urls:

```
(?u)/Search/[\w]+
```

However, I can't figure out how to set the unicode flag in the Webapp2 WSGIApplication URL patterns. The following:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('(?u)/Search/([\w]+)', SearchHandler), ... ])
```

only seems to match /Search/hello and neither of the other two, which I'm taking to mean the unicode flag is not being set.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this supported?

Comment: honestly i think this is not supposed to be done this way. here specs for uris http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html 
special characters should not be used in uris/urls

Comment: @aschmid00, perhaps I was not clear enough with my edit.  I get that the unicode characters gets percent encoded when in the URI.  However,   it seems like the webapp2 module is automatically decoding those characters back. i.e. if I had a url /Search/%20hello, my regex url pattern would need to be '[a-z ]' and not '[a-z%0-9]'

Comment: ok but why do you actually need to set the regex to a word `[\w]`, why not `/Search/(.*)`? do you want to avoid some characters in your search?

Comment: Yes, to avoid characters in the search as well as the URI (such as '/').  As you suggest, one possibility is to do `/Search/(.*)` and to have the SearchHandler check for the validity. I guess I expected that the WSGIApplication regex would handle unicode like how the Python regex does to have both options.